# Do we need the [open-source] tag on the Main Site?

Tags: discussion, specific-tag, tags

Today I found the tag [open-source](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/open-source). At first I thought that it sounds pretty interesting and I was thinking about adding a tag wiki. But when looking at the questions in that tag I saw that there were only two questions, both of which were asked more than a year ago. And most importantly: both questions are closed.

Both of these things lead me to believe that there is no real support and need for this tag. Nearly nobody uses it and the questions that currently use it are closed.

I think we should remove the tag. What does the rest of the community think?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OK, I removed both references to the tag.  It will fade away after a few days if no questions are using it.

Answer (score 7):

I'm gonna go ahead and say **no.**

As you said, there are only two questions tagged [open-source], both of them are over a year old, and both of them are closed. Nobody's using it and it doesn't seem like we have any need for it.

**Nuke it from orbit**.

Answer (score 1):

You had me persuaded. The number of questions were against it, besides being ancient history, and they were closed too. Since Citizen @JDługosz has removed them, everything's done and dusted.